# Кодировка Post запроса

Tags: android, json, post, google-translate

Я делаю POST запрос на сервер и получаю ответы в json. Когда я ввожу на русском в ответ приходят символы `"?"`. Кодировку, в которой нужноо отправлять я не знаю. Что мне делать

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t");
// Добавим данные (пара - "название - значение")
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client", "x"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "{"+text_to_translate[0]+"}"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hl", "ru"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tl", "en"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "windows-1251"));
// Выполним запрос
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

if(responseEntity!=null) {
translated_text = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
}
}
```

Пробовал с помощью:

```
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(str,"utf-8"));
```

Ответ приходит в виде "\u00D0'\u00D0°"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
translated_text = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, "UTF-8");
```